# PUB/SUB not sending data

Tags: python, zeromq, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

I'm sending data in python between two connect machines within the same network (successfully connected).

The publisher code is defined as:

```
def senderzmq(self, lat, lon):
    sock = zmq.Context().socket(zmq.PUB)
    sock.bind("tcp://*:10000")
    running = True
    while running:
        sock.send_string(f"Lat {lat}, Lon={lon}")
```

The receiver has the following format:

```
import zmq
context=zmq.Context()
socket=context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://192.168.1.35:10000")
while True:
         message=socket.recv_string()
         print(message)
```

The function senderzmq is trigger by:

```
print(f"Lat {self.lat}, Lon={self.lon}")
self.senderzmq(self.lat, self.lon)
```

self.lat and self.lon are updated from this static method:

```
@staticmethod
    def gnss(event):
        self.lat = event.latitude + LAT0
        self.lon = event.longitude + LON0
```

both LAT0 and LON0 are manually configured.

The above development works, however, the sender always sends the same data, it looks the sender remains within the while True state not listening new data. If I remove the while True, the above doesn't work. Any idea how to exit the while True but transmitting new data at each loop?

Thanks.
Raúl

Comment: I don't know anything about zmq, but doesn't your sender code run an infinite loop, continuously sending the exact same data as quickly as it can? (that `while running` loop never seems to pause or end)

Comment: Yes, it sends the exact same data and as quickly as it can. If tried to insert a running False at the end of the loop, however, doesn't work.

Comment: Please update your question with sample code which calls your `senderzmq(self ...)` method.

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample code in which there is a print of the original data gathered from some sensors and this data and using them in senderzmq function.

Comment: I see you have edited the question, but can you also show how `self.lat` and `self.lon` are updated?

Comment: Updated. Sincerely, I don't know how the rest of the code can affect the behavior of zmq or vice versa, I would like to understand how to exit the infinite loop but sending data.

Comment: Your static method cannot work by definition. Where is the `self` coming from where you have: `self.lat = event.lat ... `?

Comment: `senderzmq()` function enters an infinite loop with the initial values of `lat` and `lon`, and those values are never updated within that loop. To fix this, you need to update the `lat` and `lon` variables inside the loop (using `self`) so that it sends the current values each time.